# Redirecting entire old domain to new domain

Tags: domains, redirects

I was wondering if anyone can help with this problem. So far I've had no luck experimenting and looking on forums. I have a client that had an old website. I made a new website for him with a new domain. He asked me to redirect everything on his old site, including all the pages such as website.com/shop or website.com/about. So far I've had no luck automating this. Is there any way I can redirect every page on his old site to just the homepage of the new site?

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain

Comment: To avoid further disappointment please ensure your read our rules and faq before posting, additionally I have linked what I believe to be a solution what you need assuming that your using Apache which you failed to include in your question so its likely duplicate as well as not enough information provided.